# jQuery chosen default option shows

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am providing an option with empty value (i.e.  --- ). But it still adds the 'Select an Option' option by default to the chosen select box. I want to remove this option. Can anyone please help me with this.

The code used is,

```
   jQuery('#selectID').chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10, 'width': '271px'});
```

Thanks and Regards,

Neha

Comment: on the empty option, did you give it the attribute `selected`? or can you give us the code how you print the select list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the value of the placeholder in the declaration of the select element itself:

```
 <select data-placeholder="Choose a country..." style="width:350px;" multiple class="chosen-select">
```

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#default-text-support

Either try setting it to blank, or instead, use it rather than your empty item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this option `allow_single_deselect: true` on chosen instantiation code